# Obtener el ID eliminado para después insertarlo en otra tabla en MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, stored-procedure, trigger, sql

Necesito un Trigger que se ejecute después de un evento DML delete en una tabla, y despues agregar el numeroCuenta previamente eliminado a otra tabla llamada bitácora.
La sentencia SQL para eliminar es esta:

```
DELETE FROM CUENTA WHERE NUMEROCUENTA = "191118_181418";
```

DESPUES DE ELIMINAR LA CUENTA TENGO QUE AGREGAR EL NUMERO DE CUENTA A UNA TABLA LLAMADA BITACORA CON  UN TRIGGER Y SE TIENE QUE VER ASI:

```
SELECT * FROM BITACORA:
```

[image: TIENE QUE APARECER EL MISMO NUMERO DE CUENTA ELIMINADO]

AQUÍ ESTÁ EL TRIGGER QUE TIENE QUE INSERTAR DESPUES DE ELIMINAR:

```
 DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_del
AFTER DELETE ON cuenta FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
declare nusuarioAct varchar(50);
declare naccion varchar(50);
DECLARE fecha VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE hora VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE numCuenta VARCHAR(30);

SET nusuarioAct = concat("REALIZADO POR: ",current_user()); 
SET fecha = (DATE_FORMAT(now(),"%d%m%y"));
SET hora = (DATE_FORMAT(now(),"%k%i%s"));
SET numCuenta = CONCAT(fecha);
SET naccion = concat("ELIMINÓ LA CUENTA: ",numCuenta);
INSERT INTO bitacora(fecha,hora,uhost,usuario,accion,saldoanterior,saldoactual) VALUES(fecha,hora,"localhost",nusuarioAct,naccion,0,0);
END ; //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: y en vez de eliminar el registro por que no solo lo pones en 0 o inactivo; eso te permitirá mantener el registro para usarlo después, por que no se si haciendo un borrado como tal con `DELETE` se pueda recuperar después

Comment: Como podría recuperar el numerocuenta entonces?

Comment: Necesito poner el mismo numeroCuenta dentro de la otra tabla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías leer la documentación antes de preguntar.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

> Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access
>   columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL
>   extensions to triggers; they are not case-sensitive.
>
> In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old
>   row. In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; there is no
>   new row. In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to
>   the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to
>   the columns of the row after it is updated.

Traducción automática de Google:

> Dentro del cuerpo del activador, las palabras clave OLD y NEW le
>   permiten acceder a las columnas en las filas afectadas por un
>   activador. OLD y NEW son extensiones de MySQL para triggers; no son
>   sensibles a mayúsculas y minúsculas.
>
> En un activador INSERT, solo se puede usar NEW.col_name; no hay fila
>   vieja En un desencadenador DELETE, solo se puede usar OLD.col_name; no
>   hay nueva fila En un activador de ACTUALIZACIÓN, puede usar
>   OLD.col_name para referirse a las columnas de una fila antes de que se
>   actualice y NEW.col_name para referirse a las columnas de la fila
>   después de que se actualice.

Por lo tanto lo que estás buscando sería `OLD.numCuenta`